# Spring Cache with Redis - How to gracefully handle or even skip Caching in case of Connection Failure to Redis

Tags: spring-cache, spring-data-redis

I've enabled Caching in my Spring app and I use Redis to serve the purpose.
However, whenever a connection failure occurs, the app stops working whereas I think it had better
skip the Caching and go on with normal execution flow.

So, does anyone have any idea on how to gracefully do it in Spring ?

Here is the exception I got.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
```

Answer (score 8):

As from Spring Framework 4.1, there is a `CacheErrorHandler` that you can implement to handle such exceptions. Refer [to the javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/CacheErrorHandler.html) for more details.

You can register it by having your `@Configuration` class extends `CachingConfigurerSupport` (see `errorHandler()`).

Comment: Thanks very much for your suggestion.

My  `@Configuration` class already extends SpringBootServletInitializer, so, I tried implementing CacheErrorHandler directly instead from my `@Configuration` class. However, it doesn't seem to handle anyting like RedisConnectionFailureException.

Comment: Where have you seen a reference to `SpringBootServletInitializer` exactly? I wrote `CachingConfigurerSupport` - You need Spring Boot 1.2 (Spring 4.1) for this.

Comment: CacheErrorHandler is used only during cache operations. A Redis connection failure might be occurring higher up?

Comment: uh? What do you mean by higher up?

Comment: I think he propbably meant that when the connection is failed, the CacheErrorHandler may not be triggered

Comment: Would be nice if after prevent the error some kind of circuit breaker mechanisc were triggered. Because if there are too many calls to the cached method, all responses would take at least the timeout of Redis connection plus the actual work to get the data. I was trying to find some way to do this but I did not have much success.

Comment: I did what @StephaneNicoll said, but earlier I was getting exception even before the method with marked with Cacheable annotation invoked, but now the method executes successfully and data is fetched from DB rather than Redis, but I get exception after the function has executed. This might be where the result is being put into cache and it can't get a connetion to Redis since it is down. Any solution to this ?

Comment: Not sure how CacheHandler hanldes Configuration exception.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `CacheErrorHandler` as suggested by Stephane Nicoll. But you should make sure to make
`RedisCacheManager transactionAware` to `false` in your Redis Cache Config(to make sure the transaction is committed early when executing the caching part and the error is caught by `CacheErrorHandler` and don't wait until the end of the execution which skips `CacheErrorHandler` part). The function to set `transactionAware` to `false` looks like this:

```
    @Bean
    public RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager(LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory) {
        JdkSerializationRedisSerializer redisSerializer = new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer(getClass().getClassLoader());

        RedisCacheConfiguration redisCacheConfiguration = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
                .entryTtl(Duration.ofHours(redisDataTTL))
                .serializeValuesWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(redisSerializer));

        redisCacheConfiguration.usePrefix();

        RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager = RedisCacheManager.RedisCacheManagerBuilder.fromConnectionFactory(lettuceConnectionFactory)
                .cacheDefaults(redisCacheConfiguration)
                .build();

        redisCacheManager.setTransactionAware(false);
        return redisCacheManager;
    }
```

Comment: It works for me, but I am afraid to leave the cache out of the transaction

Answer (score -1):

Similar to what Stephane has mentioned, I have done in by consuming the error in try catch block. Adding a fall back mechanism where if Redis is not up or may be the data is not present then I fetch the data from DB.(Later if I find one then I add the same data in Redis,if it is up to maintain consistency.)